# Want a Mysql SELECT query to returns string instead of numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I HAVE THIS QUERY

```
mysql> select suppliers.valid AS 'Supplier Status' from suppliers;
+-----------------+
| Supplier Status |
+-----------------+
|               0 |
|               0 |
|               0 |
|               0 |
|               0 |
|               0 |
|               1 |
|               1 |
|               1 |
|               1 |
|               1 |
|               1 |
|               1 |
|               1 |
|               1 |
+-----------------+
```

I want the returned results to be  Supplier status is "valid" where "suppliers.valid > 0" and "invalid" where "suppliers.valid = 0".
Can someone  give me ideas  how to achieve this with mysql SQL query?

Comment: Hint:  `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a case expression:

```
Select 
CASE
WHEN suppliers.valid = 0 THEN 'Invalid'
WHEN suppliers.valid > 0 THEN 'Valid'
END AS 'Supplier Status' from suppliers;
```

Comment: You re most welcome! Please mark as answer if that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mysql> SELECT IF(CAST(suppliers.valid AS SIGNED INTEGER)=1, "String is 1", "String is 0") AS 'Supplier Status' FROM suppliers;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) statement.

```
SELECT
    CASE
       WHEN `valid` > 0 THEN 'Valid' 
       WHEN `valid` = 0 THEN 'Invalid'
       ELSE 'Error'
   END AS `Supplier_Status` 
FROM 
    `suppliers`;
```

I would strongly advise against columns with spaces in them, so I added an underscore, but you can rename that to whatever you'd like.